# How to get facebook group name list using graph API

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

i have check graph api of facebook developer [facebook group](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/groups)

i have passed my accesss token and  get method with

```
me/groups
```

And i have getting response like

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

i m getting my groups which i have created in my account.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the screenshot where you see Get Access Token click . Under the user data permission category check  user_groups then you will get the data.

[image]